# Issue when linking lapack and fftw3 libraries

Tags: macos, fortran, static-linking, lapack, fftw

I have a Fortran 90 program which uses lapack subroutines, and is successfully running on my Ubuntu system. Now I want to run it on Mac (OS X Version 10.11.4). I am using gfortran compiler as a part of gcc, installed from homebrew repositories, and lapack library, installed in /usr/local/lib/.
When I try to compile my code, I get the following error:

```
gfortran my_prog.f90 -L/usr/local/lib/ -llapack
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_daxpy_", referenced from:
      _zggbal_ in liblapack.a(zggbal.o)
...     
  "_ztrmv_", referenced from:
      _zlarft_ in liblapack.a(zlarft.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

After some google search I understood that the problem is because the linking. When I compile it like this, everything works well:

```
gfortran my_prog.f90 -llapack
```

Also when llapack from framework accelerate is used, the compiler doesn't complain.

```
gfortran my_prog.f90 -framework accelerate
```

The libraries are of x86-64 architecture:

```
lipo -info *.a
input file libfftw3.a is not a fat file
input file liblapack.a is not a fat file
Non-fat file: libfftw3.a is architecture: x86_64
Non-fat file: liblapack.a is architecture: x86_64
```

LAPACK is not the only one which gives me an error, later the same problem appears with FFTW3. Could you please give me a hint to the solution to this problem?

Comment: `daxpy` and `ztrmv` are parts of the Blas library, not lapack. Hence, could you try to link against Blas by doing `-llapack -lblas` ?

Answer (score 0):

[FFTW](http://www.fftw.org/) is not part of the [accelerate framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/Accelerate/Reference/AccelerateFWRef/index.html). If you want to use it, you need to add `-lfftw3` to the compile options as well.

If the libraries are not in the default LIBRARY_PATH, you might need to specify `-L/path/to/fftw/libs` as well. The same holds for the include path if you are using its modules `-I/path/to/fftw/includes`.

Note that the `vDSP` part of the library also provides [FFT implementations](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/Accelerate/Reference/vDSPRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/vDSP_create_fftsetup). You might not need FFTW at all.